# How can I find out what version is passed to setup in setup.py?

Tags: python, setuptools

What I'm looking for is something like:

```
python setup.py show-version
```

This is so that I can create a git tag for a release as part of build-and-release fabric job.

Since that doesn't exist I've ended up with:

```
    import setuptools
    original = sys.modules['setuptools']

    class Fake(object):
        def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
            self.args, self.kw = args, kw

    fake_setuptools = ModuleType('fake_setuptools')
    for name in dir(setuptools):
        setattr(fake_setuptools, name, Fake())

    sys.modules['setuptools'] = fake_setuptools

    with open('setup.py') as source:
        exec(source.read())

    print(fake_setuptools.setup.kw['version'])
```

Which, quite frankly, is horrible!

How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setuptools provides a --version flag to the setup script invocation.

```
$ python setup.py --version
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, if you need other metadata from the package, [jaraco.packaging](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jaraco.packaging) provides a `show` command which can be used to reveal any number of attributes from the package.

Comment: Not sure anything is needed beyond just reading the --help, can't believe I missed that :-S

Answer (score -1):

A whole bunch of information can be obtained from setup.py, including what I was looking for:

```
$ python setup.py --help
...
Information display options (just display information, ignore any commands)
  --help-commands     list all available commands
  --name              print package name
  --version (-V)      print package version
  --fullname          print <package name>-<version>
  --author            print the author's name
  --author-email      print the author's email address
  --maintainer        print the maintainer's name
  --maintainer-email  print the maintainer's email address
  --contact           print the maintainer's name if known, else the author's
  --contact-email     print the maintainer's email address if known, else the
                      author's
  --url               print the URL for this package
  --license           print the license of the package
  --licence           alias for --license
  --description       print the package description
  --long-description  print the long package description
  --platforms         print the list of platforms
  --classifiers       print the list of classifiers
  --keywords          print the list of keywords
  --provides          print the list of packages/modules provided
  --requires          print the list of packages/modules required
  --obsoletes         print the list of packages/modules made obsolete
```